# Why is SQLAlchemy Postgres ORM requiring __init__(self) for a Declarative Base?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, init

Setup: Postgres 13, Python 3.7, SQLAlchemy 1.4

The current structure uses `base.py` to create an engine, a Scoped Session, and an Augmented Base. All of this gets called
in `models.py` where we define a table Class, and is called again in `inserts.py` where we test inserting new values to
the database using the ORM. All of this is working well.

My question is regarding the `def __init__(self)` function in the `models.py` table Classes. Without this function the code will error with `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given`

As soon as I include the `__init__` function the code works properly.

I am perplexed as to why this error is being produced given that all the models are defined via the Declarative system
which means our Class should get an `__init__()` method constructor which automatically accepts keyword names that
match the columns we’ve mapped.

I suspect there is an error in how I am coding the interactions between `db_session = scoped_session` and
`Base = declarative_base(cls=Base, metadata=metadata_obj)` and the way `Base` is being passed in `class NumLimit(Base)`.

I can't quite work this out and would appreciate being directed to where I am creating this error. Thank you!

**base.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, Integer, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import declared_attr, declarative_base, scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/dev', echo=True)

db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        bind=engine,
        autocommit=False,
        autoflush=False
    )
)


# Augment the base class by using the cls argument of the declarative_base() function so all classes derived
# from Base will have a table name derived from the class name and an id primary key column.
class Base:
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


# Write all tables to schema 'collect'
metadata_obj = MetaData(schema='collect')
# Instantiate a Base class for our classes definitions
Base = declarative_base(cls=Base, metadata=metadata_obj)
```

**models.py**

```
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid


class NumLimit(Base):

    org = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    limits = Column(Integer)
    limits_rate = Column(Integer)
    rate_use = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, org, limits, allowance_rate, usage, last_usage):
        super().__init__()
        self.org = org
        self.limits = limits
        self.limits_rate = limits_rate
        self.rate_use = rate_use

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<NumLimit(org={self.org}, limits={self.limits}, limits_rate={self.limits_rate},' \
               f' rate_use={self.rate_use})>'
```

**insert.py**

```
def insert_num_limit():
    # Generate database schema based on definitions in models.py
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    # Create instances of the NumLimit class
    a_num_limit = NumLimit('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', 20, 4, 8)
    another_limit = NumLimit('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174660', 7, 2, 99)

    # Use the current session to persist data
    db_session.add_all([a_num_limit, another_limit])

    # Commit current session to database and close session
    db_session.commit()
    db_session.close()

    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parameters of the `__init__()` generated by sqlalchemy are keyword-only. It is as if the definition was:

```py
def __init__(self, *, id=None, org=None, limits=None, limits_rate=None, rate_use=None):
    self.id = id
    self.org = org
    # etc...
```

So when you try to supply the arguments positionally: `NumLimit('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', 20, 4, 8)`, you will get the error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given`, because `__init__()` indeed only takes one positional argument. If you however supply them as keyword-arguments: `NumLimit(id='123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', org=20, limits=4, limits_rate=8)` everything works.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this clearly, this is the solution!